# Unable to migrate to new schema with updated properties due to RLMRealm.setSchemaVersion block not being hit

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, realm

I have added the following two properties to my RLMObject and I can't seem to get it to update by following the docs. Here are my properties:

```
dynamic var firstName = ""
dynamic var lastName = ""
```

Here is my migration logic (in my `AppDelegate`, contained in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, which as I understand should add these properties to the realm file:

```
RLMRealm.setSchemaVersion(1, forRealmAtPath: RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath(), withMigrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {

        }

})
```

and the exception that is thrown:

```
'RLMException', reason: 'Migration is required for object type 'FilteredAccount' due to the following errors:
- Property 'firstName' has been added to latest object model.
- Property 'lastName' has been added to latest object model.'
```

When I place breakpoints in this block, they are not hit. My application crashes at the top of the AppDelegate and never executes the migration code. When I remove these properties, the application opens just fine. It also is fixed if I remove the entire realm, but obviously that's not efficient to do every time I change my data model. 
 
 Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are opening the realm before the call to `RLMRealm.setSchemaVersion`, which would definitely cause that exception.

We could verify this if you shared the full contents of your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method (presuming that is where you set up your realm).

*Edit*

Since you've added two properties to your `RLMObject` subclass and Realm does not yet support optional string properties, you'll need to assign a value for `firstName` and `lastName` to all your existing `FilteredAccount` objects inside the migration block, like so:

```
RLMRealm.setSchemaVersion(1, forRealmAtPath: RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath(), withMigrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
              migration.enumerateObjects(FilteredAccount.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    newObject["firstName"] = ""
                    newObject["lastName"] = ""
              }
        }

})
```

Comment: I do not set up my realm in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, which I'm sure is my issue. I'm using `defaultRealm` for all of my realm calls, so I don't have any setup code other then adding objects and their relevant properties to the `defaultRealm`. Is there some setup code I should be putting there even though I'm not using a different realm?

Comment: Also, the only relevant code to realm in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is posted above. The only other stuff in there is some window setup code.

Comment: Thank you! Nice to see you and your team answering questions, very cool.